# Can space and time separately be curved?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, spacetime, curvature

How can I imagine curved time, if it is not a part of four dimensional spacetime?
Similarly for space.

What are the measurable, observable consequences of these two phenomena in a laboratory or in everyday life?

Comment: Space & time are not separate, so your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: You cannot consider a hyperplane in $R^4$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between space and time?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46112/)

Comment: I do  not think that this question should be closed. See my answer below.

Comment: The spatial metric in a rotating coordinate system has non-zero curvature although the space is flat! Furthermore the duplicate is not a duplicate but a only somewhat related question (and the answers there do not answer this question).

Comment: Does similar possibility apply for time metric?

Answer (score 6):

This is not a trivial question, in my opinion. It applies to spacetimes where *there is a natural distinction between space and time*. Such spacetimes are called **static** spacetimes (even if this class could be enlarged to various directions, in particular including **stationary** spacetimes, describing the metric of rotating gravitational sources, and **conformally static** spacetimes as the cosmological models used in modern cosmology).

Sticking to static spacetimes, in particular the local spacetime around our Sun with a good approximation, the natural separation between space and time is due to the presence of a particular *Killing symmetry* which defines a natural **time direction** in spacetime. Here, $3$-spaces  ortogonal to these temporal directions are the natural notion of **physical space**. Moreover, the fact that the metric is static implies that the metric properties of these natural spaces and of the curves describing the time evolution *do not depend on the introduced notion of time*. In this sense, it makes here sense to speak about two reciprocally independent geometries, regarding space and time respectively.

The metric takes the form, referring to adapted coordinates

$$ds^2 = g_{00}(\vec{x}) dt^2 + \sum_{i,j=1}^3g_{ij}(\vec{x}) dx^i dx^j\:.$$
Above $t=x^0$ is the said notion of time, $\vec{x}=(x^1,x^2,x^3)$ denote the spatial coordinates in the natural rest frame orthogonal to the natural notion of time. This orthogonality is mathematically represented by the absence of the terms $g_{0i}=g_{i0}$ of the metric. As I said, the temporal metric $g_{00}$ and the spatial one $g_{ij}$ ($i,j=1,2,3$)  do not depend on the natural notion of time $t$, but depend on the place $\vec{x}$ in space.

It makes sense to study the geometrical properties of $g_{00}$ and $g_{ij}$ ($i,j=1,2,3$) separately. We can say that the physical space is **curved** if the metric 
$h= \sum_{i,j=1}^3g_{ij}(\vec{x}) dx^i dx^j$ cannot be transformed, by a change of coordinates, into the standard Euclidean one. In this case, some property of Euclidean geometry must fail to hold. For instance the sum of internal angles of a triangle constructed by spatial geodesics could be different from $\pi$, and the value may depend on the triangle itself. This property must not depend on time for it to be a spatial property.

The physical interpretation of the temporal geometry is more complicated. 
I cannot say that what I am about discussing technically means that   ``time is curved''. However it should substantially provide an answer to your question.

Whenever $g_{00}(\vec{x}) \neq -1$ (the latter being the ``value in flat spacetime''), several physical phenomena arise. 
What we can do, for instance, is to compare the length of a natural  time interval $\Delta t$ with the interval of time $\Delta \tau$ evaluated by an ideal clock  at rest in a position $\vec{x}$
$$\Delta \tau = \sqrt{g_{00}(\vec{x})} \Delta t\:. \tag{2}$$
All physical phenomena are stationary with respect to $t$, not $\tau$. The fact that the geometry along time direction is not trivial and depends on the position $\vec{x}$, regarding propagation of light and taking (2) into account, gives rise to the known **[gravitational redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift)**.

A much more evident phenomenon due to the fact that $g_{00}(\vec{x}) \neq -1$, *which takes place even if the spatial geometry is flat*, is the acceleration of bodies in geodesical motion  evaluated with respect to $t$. In other words, the fact that free falling bodies accelerate in a gravitational field, *also including the motion of the planets around the Sun*, in the relativistic framework, is due to the presence of a $g_{00}$ different from $-1$ and depending on the spatial position. In fact, up to multiplicative constants and with a physically sound approximation, $\nabla_{\vec{x}}g_{00}$ coincides with the classical gravitational acceleration $\vec{g}(\vec{x})$, at $\vec{x}$, which is responsible for the motion of planets in the Newtonian picture.

Answer (score 2):

The question [What makes a coordinate curved?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122659/what-makes-a-coordinate-curved) asks whether it is possible for the time coordinate to be curved while the spatial coordinates are flat.

The discussion there is probably a little too involved for this question, but the summary is that no, you cannot have a coordinate system in which the curvature is only in the time coordinate.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, this is a trivial question. Time cannot be curved independently, but space can be. Consider a piece of paper. You physically crushing the paper is an example of curving space but keeping time as it is.